# Simple Syntax error creating Postgres function with language plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I am getting a very small but irritating error while creating a Postgres function.

The function get executed when my language is *sql* but throws a syntax error

> syntax error at or near "Select"
>   LINE 14: Select * from x*

when I change the language to `plpgsql`, as I need to use control statements I need my language to be plpgsql not sql.

Here is the function defination

```
-- FUNCTION: public."HHMD"()

   DROP FUNCTION public."HHMD"();

   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."HHMD"(
        )
       RETURNS TABLE(changesets character varying)
       LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
       COST 100
       VOLATILE 
       ROWS 1000
   AS $BODY$

   Select * from x

   $BODY$;

   ALTER FUNCTION public."HHMD"()
       OWNER TO lke_new;

   COMMENT ON FUNCTION public."HHMD"()
       IS 'work!';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-structure.html) a PL/pgSQL function needs (at least) a `BEGIN` and `END` block.

To return the result of a query from within a PL/pgSQL function, you need to use [return query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

So your function should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."HHMD"()
   RETURNS TABLE(changesets character varying)
   LANGUAGE plpgsql
   COST 100
   VOLATILE 
   ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$
BEGIN --<< this is missing

   -- return the result of a query
  return query
    Select * from x;

END; --<< the corresponding END for the BEGIN
$BODY$;
```

---

Unrelated, but:

The language name is an identifier, you should **not** put it in single quotes. Use `language sql` or `language plpgsql` instead.

Comment: Single quotes was generated by the NEW FUNCTION UI in pgadmin4